# Error inside web service in Linq query I guess

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services

While calling out web service method I get error as follow:

> *GenericException
>
>   An unexpected error occured.
>   Value cannot be null.
>
>   Parameter name: source
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>
>   at QuotingGate.CalcsLV.Casco.Standard.Ergo.Calculate(VehicleQuotingParameters parameters, CascoQuote& quote) in c:\Projects\xxx\WebServices\QuotingGate\CalcsLV\Casco\Standard\Ergo.cs:line 152
>
>   at QuotingGate.CalcsBase.CalculatorBase`4.Quote(In parameters) in c:\Projects\xxx\WebServices\QuotingGate\CalcsBase\Base.cs:line 138*

On `Ergo.cs line 152` there is linq query like that:

```
var territory = from c in prices.premiums where c.tariffParam3 == "LV" select c;
```

Googled and find many cases where there was `Single` instead of `SingleOrDefault`.. but in my case its linq and relay does not matter is there any result or not, right ?

---

Prices are set here :

```
 ...
      policyDataKASKORetParam1 prices = null;
     prices = ws.GetCascoQuotesUnregistered(quote,
                            parameters.Vehicle.VIN,
                            parameters.Vehicle.Make,
                            parameters.Vehicle.Model,
                            parameters.Vehicle.ManufactureDate.Value.Year,
                            parameters.Vehicle.Value.Value,
                            parameters.Vehicle.EngineCapacity ?? 0,
                            parameters.Insurance.StartDate.Value,
                            parameters.Insurance.Currency.ToString(), irJaunakLiet, parameters.Client.Code, parameters.Vehicle.OwnerCode, irDefinetieServisi);
        enter code here
    ...
```

and the method it calls:

```
public policyDataKASKORetParam1 GetCascoQuotesUnregistered(CascoQuote quote, string vin, string make, string model, int year, int vehicleValue, int engine, DateTime policyStartDate, string currency, bool irJaunakLiet, string clientCode, string ownerCode, bool irDefinetieServisi)
        {
            policyDataKASKORetParam1 prices;
            string personCode = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Config.FixedOwnerCode) ? clientCode : Config.FixedOwnerCode;

            DateTime start = policyStartDate;
            DateTime issue = DateTime.Today;
            prices = WS.getOfferDataKASKO(SessionKey,
               personCode, // Holder Code
               null,
               null,
               vin,
               make,
               model, // Model
               year, // Year 
               engine, // Engine
               string.Empty, // Usage
               ownerCode, // Person Code
               true,
               false,
               false,
               false,
               false,
               false,
               true,
               false,
               irJaunakLiet,
               false,
               irDefinetieServisi,
               false, // TODO: All risks
               (double)vehicleValue,
               currency,
               issue,
               start,
               null,
               0d,
           null,
               null);
            if (prices.status != 0)
                quote.ErrorList.Add(new QuoteBase.Error(Errors.InsurerError, string.Format("Error message: {0}", prices.statusText)));
            return prices;
        }
```

Basically the last method calls out Web Service method.. So all together can i assume that the Web service dose not return me anything or can there be some other possibility's why it ends up null. (Don't know how to debug it, its running on remote server.. tried WCF tracing but without any results.. )

The Problem is in another country and business people are telling me that All the Web service should work so they are saying me that prices.premiums are not null.. but without debugging, cant really argue with them. Should i make a some kinda Client to run the Web Service and run it on my local machine ? Or is there some kinda another possibility to see the values of running instance ?

Also they say that Web Service hasn't been changed - also i know 100% that my code has not been changed, and all that worked fine like 10 days ago..

(PS I'm Junior who's mentor has left.. ~4 month experiences only )

Comment: Are you sure prices.premiums is not null?

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN, here's the signature of the [Where extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

As you can see, `source` is the parameter that corresponds to the collection and your error message indicates 'Parameter name: source' so my guess is that `prices.premiums` is null.